# Doctype element libxml

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am using the libxml API in C, I need to create a tag in my xml file like the following

`<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">`

Okay so I now know to use  `xmlTextWriterWriteDTD(writer, (xmlChar *)"tv", NULL, (xmlChar *)"xmltv.dtd", NULL);` but not really sure on what to do with the xmlTextWriterPtr (first parameter)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this [15-year-old forum post](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2004-March/msg00143.html) of any use? It would suggest doing `xmlTextWriterWriteDTD(writer, (xmlChar *)"tv", NULL, (xmlChar *)"xmltv.dtd", NULL);`, but I have no idea if it's at all relevant to you.

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks this helps alot, would you know if/what the first parameter will need to be pointing to?

Comment: Have a look at [`xmlCreateIntSubset`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlCreateIntSubset).